# How to save floating-point pixel values in image file

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I want to save floating-point numbers as pixels in an image file. I am currently working in OpenCV-python, but I had also tried it with Pillow (PIL). Both packages convert `float` pixel data to integer before writing them to the file.

I want to save pixel values such as:

```
(245.7865, 123.18788, 98.9866)
```

But when I read back the image file I get:

```
(246, 123, 99)
```

Somehow my floating-point numbers get rounded off and converted to integers.
How to stop PIL or OpenCV from converting them to integer?

Comment: Maybe use an image format that supports floats, such as TIFF, or PFM... http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pfm.html

Comment: Or use `OpenCV::FileStorage`.

Comment: Python Wand can save to TIFF or PFM.

Answer (score 3):

Raster images are normally stored as integer values only. Instead save the numpy array [directly](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) like so

```
x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
with open('x.npy', 'wb') as f:
    numpy.save(f, x)
```

Then load the variable back like so

```
x = numpy.load('x.npy')
```

Other alternatives include

- Save one or more GRAY16 png images, with your floats multiplied and truncated.
- Use the [Netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pfm.html) format supporting floats.
- Save a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you observe depends on the file format in which you save the image. Few image formats have a specification for floating-point pixel values. Though some do, first and foremost TIFF.

To demonstrate the desired behavior with a TIFF image writer, consider the following script. It uses the versatile image input/output library [ImageIO](https://pypi.org/project/imageio), which relies on PILlow as one of its back-ends:

```
# Use Stack Overflow logo as sample image.
import imageio
logo = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/logo.png'
image = imageio.imread(logo)

# Normalize to 1. Pixel values are now floating-point.
image = image / image.max()

# Save as image file and read back in.
format = 'tiff'
imageio.imwrite(f'image.{format}', image)
print(f'wrote: {image.dtype}')
image = imageio.imread(f'image.{format}')
print(f'read:  {image.dtype}')
```

The output of that script is:

```
wrote: float64
read:  float64
```

If, on the other hand, you change the format to PNG (`format = 'png'` in the code), the output is:

```
Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [0, 1].
Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.
wrote: float64
read:  uint8
```

Comment: This solution is great, however, do you have any idea on why the resulting file can't be opened? I finally managed to save and recover the file, but I can't open it using any of the photo viewers which come with Windows. Any idea would be much appreciated!